# All double slit experiment explanations are bad

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

If I aim my laser at the wall in front of me, I will not see it showing up on the wall left to me.

Now with the double slit experiment. When you say a beam of light, ok a thick beam of light passes through both slits and some of it will hit the space between two slits and won’t even pass. Now when it comes to individual particles, how is the setup working? How is the shooter aiming at the slit? If I aim a thin beam of laser to one of the slits, it will not pass the other. Same goes for individual particles. I think my issue is with imprecision in explanations of the setup.

Comment: You could have e.g. an [electron gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_gun) with a beam broad enough to cover both the slits. I'm pretty sure you need the beam to be broad enough to cover both slits, or you'd know which slit it passes through and therefore get no interference pattern.

Comment: see this classroom experiment with single photons and a double stli: https://www.sps.ch/artikel/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/

Answer (score 0):

You aim the laser beam so that it goes through both slits. Then you put filters in front of the beam so that the probability of detecting more than one photon in the experiment at a time is negligible. You can check whether the beam is still going through both slits by placing detectors after each slit and check that the detectors go off at the expected rate.